# X axis Time scale display issue using python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

As picture shows, the X axis Time will be refreshed continually. When X axis Time scale is more and more, the Time scale will be dense and overlapped. Wondering is there any way to keep the X axis scale just the newest several values no matter how the Time is refreshed?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some more information on your data? How is the time axis becoming more and more? Are you constantly adding more data?
You can always specify fixed values for your X-axis, e.g. last 10 days.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I use the csv file which can refresh the data automatically at short intervals to draw graph. So when I run the script a long time, there will be mass of data, and the X axis Time scale will be dense and not easy to see clearly. I just want to show the X scale the newest several value no matter how long time I run the script.